# How can I leverage machine learning for log analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, training, language-model, llm

I am new to data science and trying to find possibilities of using datascience in tasks. I have a set of logs which I want to convert to json. The logs are more or less of same format and I can write a script which parse them or aggregate them but instead of doing it manually I want to use help of machine learning. This thought is also inspired by the fact that at sometime some new log line may come. I guess pre-trained LLM models can identify the context and information from logs. But I am not sure how exactly can ML be used for for this purpose? The question may sound stupid but please pardon.

Answer (score 1):

this question is not stupid, it's great that you want to extract knowledge from logs. However, if you are at the very beginning of this journey, I wouldn't recommend not pondering over LLM but starting from simpler stuff. If I were you, I would start by parsing these logs and organizing an infrastructure for doing that regularly (in a real-time best). Having done that you can consider your first NLP analysis, but for me, the key would be to do something hands-on with this data like visualizing on the [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboard or creating an alerting. When you trudge along this data, you will see what has potential.